# What does a NULL array in C actually contain?

Tags: c, arrays, null

Say a function in C takes an array as its input, and someones passes in NULL for the array. If the function returned array[0] or any number, what would be returned? 0? NULL? Is it the same if you try to do math or other things with array[0]? Most importantly, how can I have my function check if it's been passed a NULL array?

Comment: You cannot pass arrays as function parameters in C. You can only pass pointers. To check the value of a pointer, use an `if` statement.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, makes sense. I'm still getting used to pointers. It won't let me check if the pointer is equal to "NULL," so is it the same thing if I check if it is equal to zero?

Comment: Keep reading your text book. You should definitely be able to compare a pointer with `NULL`, but you probably forgot to `#include <stddef.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, accessing `array[0]` would dereference the NULL pointer, which is undefined behaviour (and in most cases will cause your program to crash).

You can check if you've been passed a NULL pointer by simply comparing the `array` with NULL:

```
if(array == NULL) {
  return 0;
} else {
  return array[0];
}
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that an API in which this implementation makes sense would be a total design disaster.

Comment: @KerrekSB disagree; e.g. it could be defined so that a null pointer behaves the same as a zero-filled array

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just had to use zero instead of null, as I didn't define it anywhere.

Comment: @Clotex Ahh, yes sorry. NULL is defined in a bunch of standard libraries so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your pointer as `NULL (0)`, then reading of `array[0]` will be done from memory position `0`. Since array[0] and `0[array]` is the same thing, you can think of memory position like this:

```
data = *(type_of_pointer *)(array + key * sizeof(type_of_pointer));
```

In your case:

```
data = *(type_of_pointer *)(0 + 0 * sizeof(type_of_pointer));
```

So your reading would be done from memory location `0`. In most cases this will crash your program, but in general it is unknown behaviour.

Reading `array[5]` would do this:

```
data = *(type_of_pointer *)(array + 5 * sizeof(type_of_pointer));
```

Comment: Reading `array[0]` is undefined behaviour in that case. On most systems it will not attempt to read memory position 0.

Comment: True, but I gave general answer.